# How to insert "not duplicate" data as primary key

Tags: mysql

I wanna insert data into the account table from the info table, and the accountId in the account table is primary key, to make sure it's not duplicate,
I use count(*) to get the different name.

But count(*) always get the first time value, that mean every insert data have same accountId.

How can I do?

```
INSERT INTO `account`(`accountId`, `password`, `email`) 
SELECT CONCAT('test',(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `account`)),'testpassword',`email` FROM `info`
```

Comment: What is '`auto_random`'? And have you seen [this](https://forums.mysql.com/read.php?24,425424,425491)? But why random? Auto-incrementing primary keys are much better for the user to deal with, and more efficient on insert.

Comment: oh! that's right. But how to do it?

Comment: Err, `auto_increment`?

Comment: What about `unique` index on that column?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to avoid duplicates of ID's you must auto increment the field example

```
alter table `tableName` modify column `Column_name` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY 
KEY;
```

Comment: But the primary column store the name of account, it need not only number also English letter.

Comment: @KevinChen Why? It should only be the account number. Name is in a separate column, surely.

Comment: Name can be duplicate but ID's not, combining id+name in one column is not appropriate to apply